# Web sites where I can post divrei Torah

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, internet, ramban

Can anyone suggest a good site where I can post a weekly list of marei mekomos in Ramban on the Parsha?

Comment: Please clarify - Do you mean that you want a place where you can post your sources or a place where you can find others' sources? Please edit your question to make this clear, and edit your title to more specifically fit the question.

Comment: I want to post a list of marei mekomos.

Comment: I just found this I think Issac you should look into this for the site you may be able to take it to the next level with out anyone else if you can get it done

Comment: http://www.bhol.co.il/Article.aspx?id=23072

Comment: It is in Hebrew but I think you can understand

Comment: or at least get yourself a solid Vacation(;

Comment: SimchasTorah, Thanks for the pointer. I'll keep it in mind. I've seen some other promising grant opportunities, too. For now, though, I'm going to stick with the current plan. It's not just money that I'm looking to save.

Comment: so the more money the better, right?

Comment: AY, Rav Yerachmiel Fried came out a number of years ago with a small kuntres pointing out what are in his humble opinion the hashkafically essential Rambans. Some may have reservations about choosing which are essential, but he is the only one who did it and it could prove to be an invaluable tool for what you are doing.

Comment: In my opinion, his opinion should not be taken lightly!

Comment: @AY - Did you ever find a place to publish your lists? I am sure people would be eager to see them.

Comment: No,  I did not.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you should create a [blog](http://www.blogger.com/).

Comment: Google Documents (https://docs.google.com/) is probably more suited for this particular application. The reverse-chronological-order format of a blog is not so great for an index of mareh mekomos.

Comment: Or perhaps a wiki.

Comment: I'm looking for a place where people already look, not to create a new site.

Comment: But I thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: If you can't find an existing forum where your new content would fit, you could always create a new forum (blog/wiki/whatever) and promote it in existing fora. That's how this site got going.

Answer (score 4):

While your description is rather vague, I believe that you will discover a fair degree of success on Judaism Codidact's "[Divrei Torah](https://judaism.codidact.com/categories/43)" section.

Answer (score 1):

How about [GlobalYeshiva](http://www.globalyeshiva.com/)? I know some people post things of this sort there.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [shortvort.com](http://www.shortvort.com/) - it is a website full of very nice, small divrei Torah covering the full gamut of Jewish thought.

You can submit a 'vort' [here](http://www.shortvort.com/submit/) where it also lists the site's policy.